# Is it possible to access x11 clipboard in a untrusted X11 client?

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

How can I access x11 clipboard in a remote untrusted client(ssh x11 forwarding)? All I need is the x11 clipboard and I don't want to enable trusted x11 forwarding(which would give the remote client much more control over my computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find some shared network clipboard tools out there, but as far as I am aware, none of them are easy to install or setup (most require compiling from source).
I have added clipboard sharing to [xpra](http://xpra.org/) for various platforms, I believe you could use it to achieve what you want. Xpra is normally used for forwarding windows and sound (as well as clipboard), but there are switches to disable all the stuff you don't need. (ie: "--no-windows", "--no-speaker", ..)
Note: if you want to connect to an existing X11 display (rather than a new dedicated xpra session), you will have to use "xpra shadow :0" instead of "xpra start ..."
Then from the client, just "xpra attach ssh:SERVER:0"

Alternatively, if you are happy to use the command line and scripting, there is always xclip.